# Jolt transformation for one to many relationship

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Please help me with the jolt transformation. This transformation will follow the rule as mentioned below:

If `tierId` matches with `sourceNodeID` at least once, then

**a**. `name` will be `sourceNodename` and

**b**. `targetNodeID` will be matched with `tierId` in the whole array, then it
will create one to many relationship with `targetNodeID`

**input** :

```json
[
  {
    "name": "account-management--1",
    "tierId": 206183,
    "sourceNodeID": "206183",
    "targetNodeID": "206184"
  },
  {
    "name": "biz-loan-services--1",
    "tierId": 206184,
    "sourceNodeID": "206183",
    "targetNodeID": "206184"
  },
  {
    "name": "biz-loan-services--2",
    "tierId": 206184,
    "sourceNodeID": "206183",
    "targetNodeID": "206184"
  }
]
```

There could be any number of input for `tireId` matching with `sourceNodeID` or `targetNodeID`.

**expected output** :

```json
[
  {
    "sourceNodename": "account-management--1",
    "tierId": 206183,
    "sourceNodeID": "206183",
    "targetNodeID": "206184"
    "targetNodename": "biz-loan-services--1"
  },
 {
    "sourceNodename": "account-management--1",
    "tierId": 206183,
    "sourceNodeID": "206183",
    "targetNodeID": "206184"
    "targetNodename": "biz-loan-services--2"
  }
]
```

Comment: That's fairly complex logic, it might be easier to use ScriptedTransformRecord with a language like Groovy rather than fighting with the JOLT DSL to do the matching and one-to-many generation.

Comment: Thanks for responding @mattyb, can you please explain or help in ScriptedTransformRecord

Comment: Are you familiar with Groovy or Java? I am trying to come up with a ScriptedTransformRecord in Jython but am still working on it, but it should be pretty straightforward in Groovy or Java if you are familiar with them

Comment: Thank you @mattyb, for your response. I have tried with querryRecord, and it worked for me!